# Apache Ignite cluster Java Client

Tags: java, ignite

How do I connect to Apache ignite cluster from Java client from outside cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You would establish such connection with a Thin Client:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/thin-clients